# Download a pdf file using PHP with a search form

Tags: php, pdf, download

I've created a search form where the user would input the image code and when searched it will let the user download the file. Below is my code

```
<html>
          <head>
            <title>Search  Contacts</title>
          </head>
          <body>

            <h3>Search Client File</h3>
            <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
              Type the File Code:<br><br>
                  <input  type="text" name="fcode">
            <br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>

<?php
$filecode=$_POST["fcode"];
     if (!empty($filecode))
     {
$file="/var/www/website/$filecode.pdf";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
     }
     else
     {
       echo "No Results";
     }

        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that the downloaded file is unable to be viewed, or unviewable, what seems to be the problem with my code?

Comment: Is the markup at the top of the file also being rendered to the output?  If so, no PDF reader is going to understand it.  Usually responding with a file would happen in a PHP script all by itself, not surrounded by additional markup.

Comment: @David Sorry, but what do you mean by the "markup"

Comment: "Markup" is the "M" in "HTML".  What I mean is that if the response contains both HTML and the PDF file then it's not a valid PDF.

Comment: @David Could you suggest how i should correct this?

Comment: Well, first you'll want to confirm if this is in fact the error.  This can probably be confirmed in the browser's debugging tools by examining the response.  If the response contains the HTML in this page, then that's the problem.  (There may be additional problems, but to diagnose them you'd need to correct this one.)  I'm not entirely sure that's the problem, since it *should* give you an error about modifying headers after the content has already started.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never work. You are outputting your HTML form at the start of every execution of the code. If a download was requested, the download will be appended to that HTML page. And the `header()` calls will fail as well with "headers already sent".

If you're submitting your form to the same page, you need to have your download code FIRST:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... download stuff here
   exit(); // critical - don't let the html get output
}

... html form here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made it to work, below is the code for reference.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    ob_end_flush();
    readfile($file);
```